# Import JS web assembly into TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, webassembly

I'm trying to use [wasm-clingo](https://github.com/domoritz/wasm-clingo) in my TypeScript React project. I tried to write my own `d.ts` file for the project:

```
// wasm-clingo.d.ts
declare module 'wasm-clingo' {
  export const Module: any;
}
```

and import like this:

```
import { Module } from 'wasm-clingo';
```

but when I `console.log(Module)` it says `undefined`. What did I do wrong?

Notes:

- [clingo.js](https://github.com/domoritz/wasm-clingo/blob/master/clingo.js) is the main js file.
- [index.html](https://github.com/domoritz/wasm-clingo/blob/master/index.html) and [index_amd.html](https://github.com/domoritz/wasm-clingo/blob/master/index_amd.html) are two example pages

## Solution:

I solved the problem like this:

```
// wasm-clingo.d.ts
declare module 'wasm-clingo' {
  const Clingo: (Module: any) => Promise<any>;
  namespace Clingo {}
  export = Clingo;
}
```

and

```
import * as Clingo from 'wasm-clingo';
```

[**Here's the source for this solution**](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565#issuecomment-155216760)

Comment: A TypeScript declaration file `.d.ts` only declares types -- it doesn't actually export anything. Can you try `import Module from 'wasm-clingo'`?

Answer (score 5):

I know you found a solution acceptable to you; however, you don't really have any types here, you just have `Module` declared as `any`, which gives you no typescript benefits at all. In a similar situation I used `@types/emscripten`, which provides full type definitions for web assembly modules compiled using emscripten. You simply need to do:

`npm install --save-dev @types/emscripten`

then change your `tsconfig.json` `types` array to add an entry for `emscripten`.
After that you can just write `Module.ccall(...)` etc. If you like you could of course write `const Clingo = Module` and then make calls against that if you want a more descriptive name than `Module` (which is a terrible name!).

You're welcome ;)

Comment: Can you maybe give an example please. Also how does one wrap classes?

Comment: Classes are kind of weird because they live on the module object. You'll probably have to use class expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `wasm-clingo` exports the module itself but `import { Module } from 'wasm-clingo'` expects a property.

Try

```
import Clingo_ from 'wasm-clingo';
const Clingo: typeof Clingo_ = (Clingo_ as any).default || Clingo_;
```